# How to add a enviroment variable without GUI

Tags: environment-variables, path, microsoft-surface, windows-rt

Is there a way how I can add a new environment variable specifically `PATH` without going into control panel etc.

Is there a file I can edit for this or a command line argument that can do the same thing?

Comment: Use `set` or `setx`. See the duplicate question link as well as [set](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) and [setx](http://ss64.com/nt/setx.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can actually define one by issuing  `set your_var=some_value` in a cmd window. 
If you want to get the value you have to issue `%your_var%`.

The same works with modifying environment variables like path. To expand it you can for example do something like this `set path=%path%;some_dir`.

But keep in mind that such modifications just stay for your current cmd session/window.